# VB code to change specific character in title

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

Part of my job for work is to create & update documents for clients to use, there are 50+ documents. And every time we update to a new version the documents must be updated as well (add new images & definitions etc...). Updating all of the titles is a very tedious & time consuming process so, I have been writing VBA code within MS-Word that will update documents with a new Saved Name & save it to a specific folder. The issue I can't figure out is how to update only specific characters within the name of the document.
Ex.of Document titles are 6.4.0.4 QA Admin, 6.5.0.5 Estimation, 6.5.0.6 Navigation, let's say that I am trying to update just the numbers in the title of the document to the current version, which is 6.6.0.5.

I've already got code that will Save the doc as new, to a destination that I choose, but the name is being replace with 6.6.0.5 and cutting off the remainder of the title.
Below is what I have so far that works, I have tried entering Left(strDocName, intPos - 6 ) to locate the 6th character from the left in the name and update it, but have not had any luck.. Any advice/help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Update_Doc_Name_Path()
'
' Updates the document name and path
'
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\Jpaulk\Desktop\MacTest\"
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="6.6.0.5 Test.docx", FileFormat:= _
        wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
        :=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts _
        :=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
        SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you are saying is currently happening.

```
"...but the name is being replace with 6.6.0.5 and cutting off the remainder of the title."
```

The code you shared appears to work fine.

I will suggest as an answer though an easier way to do this if you are just changing saved filenames. There is an add-in to Word called **AuthorTec File Doctor** that will do this without you having to open each individual file. You can run it from any open document and it will work will all documents you select from a directory.

Do a web search on **AuthorTec File Doctor** and see if might help. I am the author of the add-in and the add-in is free.

If the add-in does not meet your needs consider using the VBA method `Replace` to swap the version numbers. Below is revised code that you can use as an example:

```
Sub Update_Doc_Name_Path_Revised()
'
' Updates the document name and path
'
' A path separator is used so that this routine can run on by Windows and Mac versions of Word
' The macro shows how the file could be saved to a different folder, the folder would
' aready have to exist on the computer. A Replace method could also be used to alter the
' pathname. For example ~/documents/Test might be altered to ~/documents/newTest

    Dim Sep As String
    Dim newPathName As String, newFileName As String
    Dim oldVersion As String, newVersion As String

    oldVersion = "6.6.0.5"
    newVersion = "6.6.0.6"
    Sep = Application.PathSeparator
    newPathName = ActiveDocument.path
    newFileName = ActiveDocument.Name

    newFileName = Replace(newFileName, oldVersion, newVersion)
    newPathName = newPathName & Sep & "Test" & Sep

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 newPathName & newFileName, wdFormatXMLDocument

End Sub
```

Comment: Rich, thank you for your reply- I looked into the AuthorTec and it definitely could be what I would need to quickly rename documents, unfortunately we do not have the ability to download any file types.

Apologies for not being clear on what I am looking for help with.
Currently I have 50+ docs that I have been updating content in, they have titles like the following, 6.5.0.4 "QA Admin", what I would like to do is keep the part that's in quotes and change the numbers in the title to match the current software version.
Does this help to clarify?

Comment: @Jpaulk, I have edited my answer based on your comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review my entry and respond with your code. It has definitely helped me refine the code that I am creating. 
Is there any method that you know of that would retain the right portion of a document title while replacing the left values?

Comment: @Jpaulk, that's what the code I supplied does ... have you tested it?

Comment: Strange.. When I copied the full code to see the outcome, it was saving the Document title as 6.6.0.66.6.0.6 Test and each time you run the macro it adds 6.6.0.6 to the current title instead of replacing.